# Parsing tables, cells with Html agility in C#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I need to parse Html code. More specifically, parse each  cell of every  rows in all tables. Each row represent a single object and each cell represent different properties. I want to parse these to be able to write an XML file with every data inside (without the useless HTML code). I have successfully been able to parse each column from the HTML file but now I don't know what my options are for writing this to an XML file. I am baffled.

HTML:

```
<tr><tr> 
<td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF"> 
    1
</td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="left"> 
        <a href="/ice/player.htm?id=8471675">Sidney Crosby</a> 
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="center"> 
        PIT
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="center"> 
        C
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        39
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        32
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        33
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox sorted" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #E0E0E0" align="right"> 
        <font color="#000000"> 
            65
        </font> 
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        20
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        29
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        10
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        1
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        3
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        0
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        154
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        20.8
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        21:54
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        22.6
    </td> 
    <td class="statBox" style="border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF" align="right"> 
        55.7
    </td> 
</tr></tr>
```

C#:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Stats
{
    class StatsParser
    {
        private string htmlCode;
        private static string fileName = "[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " NHL Stats].xml";

        public StatsParser(string htmlCode)
        {
            this.htmlCode = htmlCode;
            this.ParseHtml();
        }

        public void ParseHtml()
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);

        try
        {
            // Get all tables in the document
            HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");

            // Iterate all rows in the first table
            HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[0].SelectNodes(".//tr");
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
            {

                // Iterate all columns in this row
                HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[@class='statBox']");
                for (int j = 0; j < cols.Count; ++j)
                {

                    // Get the value of the column and print it
                    string value = cols[j].InnerText;
                    if (value!="")
                        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(value);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Exception!!");
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Stats Date="2011-01-01">
  <Player Rank="1">
    <Name>Sidney Crosby</Name>
    <Team>PIT</Team>
    <Position>C</Position>
    <GamesPlayed>39</GamesPlayed>
    <Goals>32</Goals>
    <Assists>33</Assists>
  </Player>
</Stats>
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of the XML output you'd like?

Comment: FWIW, you could greatly simplify your "parsing" code if you used XPath more effectively.  Something like: `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[1]/tr/td[@class='statBox']")` would give you all the `statBox` cells in the first table.

Comment: @Cameron, I have added a excerpt of XML as I would like to have it...

Comment: @Jeff, I haven't really parsed the fields in my code yet because if would be complicated to iterate through the columns to compile 17 different columns of distinct data, so I was wondering if I could just stream an output into an XML file instead and if there is a simple way to do this in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around MSDN, I finally found an implementation solution to my problem:

```
    using System;
    using HtmlAgilityPack;
    using System.Xml;

    namespace HockeyStats
    {
        class StatsParser
        {
            private string htmlCode;
            private static string fileName = "[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " NHL Stats].xml";

            public StatsParser(string htmlCode)
            {
                this.htmlCode = htmlCode;

                this.ParseHtml();
            }

            public void ParseHtml()
            {

                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
                XmlWriter writer = null;

                try
                {
                    // Create an XmlWriterSettings object with the correct options. 
                    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                    settings.Indent = true;
                    settings.IndentChars = ("  ");
                    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;

                    // Create the XmlWriter object and write some content.
                    writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"..\..\"+fileName, settings);
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Stats");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

                // Iterate all rows within another row
                HtmlNodeCollection rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//tr/tr");
                for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    // Iterate all columns in this row
                    HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[@class='statBox']");
                    for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
                    {
                                switch (j)
                                {
                                    case 0:
                                        {
                                            writer.WriteStartElement("Player");
                                            writer.WriteAttributeString("Rank", cols[j].InnerText.Trim()); break;
                                        }
                                    case 1: writer.WriteElementString("Name", cols[j].InnerText.Trim()); break;
                                    case 2: writer.WriteElementString("Team", cols[j].InnerText.Trim()); break;
                                    case 3: writer.WriteElementString("Pos", cols[j].InnerText.Trim()); break;
                                    case 4: writer.WriteElementString("GP", cols[j].InnerText.Trim()); break;
                                    case 5: writer.WriteElementString("G", cols[j].InnerText.Trim()); break;
                                    case 6: writer.WriteElementString("A", cols[j].InnerText.Trim()); break;
                                    case 7: writer.WriteElementString("PlusMinus", cols[j].InnerText.Trim()); break;
                                    case 8: writer.WriteElementString("PIM", cols[j].InnerText); break;
                                    case 9: writer.WriteElementString("PP", cols[j].InnerText); break;
                                    case 10: writer.WriteElementString("SH", cols[j].InnerText); break;
                                    case 11: writer.WriteElementString("GW", cols[j].InnerText); break;
                                    case 12: writer.WriteElementString("OT", cols[j].InnerText); break;
                                    case 13: writer.WriteElementString("Shots", cols[j].InnerText); break;
                                    case 14: writer.WriteElementString("ShotPctg", cols[j].InnerText); break;
                                    case 15: writer.WriteElementString("TOIPerGame", cols[j].InnerText); break;
                                    case 16: writer.WriteElementString("ShiftsPerGame", cols[j].InnerText); break;
                                    case 17: writer.WriteElementString("FOWinPctg", cols[j].InnerText); break;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.Flush();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (writer != null)
                        writer.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

which gives the following XML file as an output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Stats Date="2011-01-01">
 <Player Rank="1">
  <Name>Sidney Crosby</Name> 
  <Team>PIT</Team> 
  <Pos>C</Pos> 
  <GP>39</GP> 
  <G>32</G> 
  <A>33</A> 
  <PlusMinus>20</PlusMinus> 
  <PIM>29</PIM> 
  <PP>10</PP> 
  <SH>1</SH> 
  <GW>3</GW> 
  <Shots>0</Shots> 
  <ShotPctg>154</ShotPctg> 
  <TOIPerGame>20.8</TOIPerGame> 
  <ShiftsPerGame>21:54</ShiftsPerGame> 
  <FOWinPctg>22.6</FOWinPctg> 
 </Player>
</Stats>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I had meant in my comment was that you're doing in code (the nested loops) what having the right XPath can do for you.  Using LINQ-to-XML can make this even more simpler to write.  But now that we see how you want your XML file formatted, we can offer our own answers.  I'd write the `ParseHtml()` method like so:

```
public void ParseHtml()
{
    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
    var cells = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                                    // use the right XPath rather than looping manually
                       .SelectNodes(@"//tr/tr/td[@class='statBox']")
                       .Select(node => node.InnerText.Trim())
                       .ToList();
    var elementNames = new[] { "Name", "Team", "Pos", "GP", "G", "A", "PlusMinus", "PIM", "PP", "SH", "GW", "OT", "Shots", "ShotPctg", "TOIPerGame", "ShiftsPerGame", "FOWinPctg", "UnknownField" };
    var xmlDoc =
        new XElement("Stats", new XAttribute("Date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()),
            new XElement("Player", new XAttribute("Rank", cells.First()),
                // generate the elements based on the parsed cells
                cells.Skip(1)
                     .Zip(elementNames, (Value, Name) => new XElement(Name, Value))
                     .Where(element => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Value))
            )
        );

    // save to your file
    xmlDoc.Save(filepath);
}
```

Produces the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stats Date="1/3/2011">
  <Player Rank="1">
    <Name>Sidney Crosby</Name>
    <Team>PIT</Team>
    <Pos>C</Pos>
    <GP>39</GP>
    <G>32</G>
    <A>33</A>
    <PlusMinus>20</PlusMinus>
    <PIM>29</PIM>
    <PP>10</PP>
    <SH>1</SH>
    <GW>3</GW>
    <Shots>0</Shots>
    <ShotPctg>154</ShotPctg>
    <TOIPerGame>20.8</TOIPerGame>
    <ShiftsPerGame>21:54</ShiftsPerGame>
    <FOWinPctg>22.6</FOWinPctg>
    <UnknownField>55.7</UnknownField>
  </Player>
</Stats>
```

Comment: I am trying to build your ParseHtml() method but I am getting an error for the ".Select" property: Error 1 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'SelectSingleNode' and no extension method 'SelectSingleNode' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I have fixed that issue... The 55.7 value is added now.

Comment: P.S., I have version 1.4.0.0 of HtmlAgilityPack and .NET 3.5