# get data from div(js) using c# winforms

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms

here is a part of HTML where contains JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/left-menu.js"></script>
```

This is part of code that displays at some time:

```
<div id="bx"></div> 
And this is left-menu.js

var v = new Date();
var sec_raznica = c * 1000 - v.getTime();
var greenwich = ((v.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * -1) - (120 * 60)) * -1000;

function t() {

 var time = new Date();
 time = Math.floor(time.getTime());
 var t = new Date(time + sec_raznica + greenwich);

 var date1 = t.getDate();
 var date2 = t.getMonth() + 1;
 var time1 = t.getHours();
 var time2 = t.getMinutes();
 var time3 = t.getSeconds();

 if (date1 < 10) date1 = "0" + date1;
 if (date2 < 10) date2 = "0" + date2;
 if (time1 < 10) time1 = "0" + time1;
 if (time2 < 10) time2 = "0" + time2;
 if (time3 < 10) time3 = "0" + time3;

document.getElementById("bx").innerHTML = date1 + "." + date2 + " " + time1 + ":" +           time2 + ":" + time3;
window.setTimeout("t();", 1000);
}
window.onload = t;
```

How do I get this data from div with `id="bx"` without using webBrowser?

Comment: Question is very unclear here. Tag indicates this a winforms issue but it sounds more like ASP .NET. Assuming you're using ASP .NET, if you want to access something set by client side JScript in your ASP .NET code-behind, the most common method is to set the value of a hidden field and access the value in the code behind.

Comment: This is not ASP.NET sorry, i need help in winforms, because i want represent game from web browser to desktop application.

Comment: @user2432192 - I think you need a HTML parser. Something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573012/parsing-tables-cells-with-html-agility-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: Parser will return void value InnerText="";