# Parsing HTML to get the key and value

Tags: c#, html, .net, parsing, html-agility-pack

I use `HTMLAgility` to parse HTML Document.

I downloaded the dll from [codeplex](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)  and `referenced` it to my project.

Now, all my need is to parse this HTML (below):

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
//......................
<tbody ID='image'>
<tr><td>Video Codec</td><td colspan=2>JPEG (8192 KBytes)</td></tr>
</BODY>
```

Now, I need to retrieve `Video Codec` and its value `JPEG` from the above HTML.

I know that I can use `HTMLAgility` but how to do that?

```
            var document = new HtmlDocument();
            string htmlString = "<tbody ID='image'>";
            document.LoadHtml(htmlString);
            // how to get the Video Codec and its value `JPEG` ?
```

Any pointers is much appreciated.

EDIT:

I was able to proceed from @itedi 's answer to a bit but still stuck up.

```
var cells = document.DocumentNode
                // use the right XPath rather than looping manually
                               .SelectNodes(@"//table")
                               .ToList();

            var tbodies = cells.First().SelectNodes(@"//tbody").ToList();
```

gives me all the `tbody`'s but how to print the values from it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573012/parsing-tables-cells-with-html-agility-in-c-sharp if not this should help you on your way.

Comment: @itedi: Thanks itedi. Kindly see my `edit`. I was able to proceed up to the specified point and then struck up. Any pointers is greatly helpful. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

A much lighter way would be using regex:

```
string s = @"<tbody ID='image'>
                    <tr><td>Video Codec</td><td colspan=2>JPEG (8192 KBytes)</td></tr>
                    </BODY>";
var results = Regex.Match(s, "<td>Video Codec</td><td.*?>(.+?)</td>").Groups[1];
```

Returns: 
JPEG (8192 KBytes)